# read db as all text

Tags: database, overriding, xlsx

Im reading a xlsx file as a db to do some work

i noticed that its reading some feilds in as int and date even though i just want it all to come in as text . is there anyway to override this feature?

Code below

(feel free to point out anything i could be doing better with my code as well)

```
  private DataSet ExceltoDT(OpenFileDialog dialog)
    {
        try
        {
            string connst = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + dialog.FileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO\";";
            string sheet = "Sheet1$";
            string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheet + "]";
            //string Table = "081710";
            OleDbConnection xlsdb = new OleDbConnection(connst);
            xlsdb.Open();
            OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(strSQL, xlsdb);
            DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
            adp.Fill(ds2);


            adp.Dispose();
            xlsdb.Close();
            xlsdb.Dispose();

            return ds2;
        }
        catch (StackOverflowException stack_ex2)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("(2007 Excel file) Stack Overflowed!" + "\n" + stack_ex2.Message);
            return null;

        }
        catch (OleDbException ex_oledb2)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An OleDb Error Thrown!" + "\n" + ex_oledb2.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `'` (apostrophe) in front of every cell value. That will tell Excel "Treat this as text even when it looks like a number/date/whatever".

Not what you want? Then don't use the DB connector because it's badly broken. You'll notice that when you have a column with cells that are mixed. In that case, the DB driver will look at the first 8 rows and set the type to the majority of types it finds and return NULL for anything in that column that doesn't fit. [You can fix that](http://blog.lab49.com/archives/196) by hacking your registry.

Instead use the OLE API to open the Workbook and then start from there, reading row by row, converting the data as you need (this [long list of posts](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsto/thread/b6e8a28c-6760-4e86-a1aa-e2ce9ec36380/) should contain about every possible way to access Excel from C# plus all the bugs and problems you can encounter).

Comment: do you ahve a good example of the old api to read a xls or xlsx?

Comment: You can find the Excel API here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa209782(office.10).aspx  PS: It's OLE, not "old" :-)